# Is the Dungeon Magazine 4e Adventure List spreadsheet still available?

Tags: dnd-4e, published-adventures, online-resources

[This link](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AgVSv2n9lvwndGEyOVhILURBLVBFWWMwNlJIcjdIZnc&hl=fr&output=html) used to go to a spreadsheet with all the 4E adventures published in Dungeon Magazine (and possibly some others, IIRC) during that edition's duration. I remember it listed out each adventure by name, start/end level, adventure path, and maybe even a little summary blurb.

However, the spreadsheet behind that link seems to have disappeared into the digital ether, and I can't find a copy of it in my own google drive (implying I never made a copy of it).

Does anyone happen to have a copy of that spreadsheet that they could share, and/or other resources that would let me sort through the many adventures from 4E Dungeon Magazine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this link still works for me:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vPhUENrJf9oE1e0rAatmf05SRU7fU--X-f4EN1SIzb8/pub?hl=fr&output=html

Answer (score 6):

Although David Igoe's provided link is *precisely* what I was looking for, I am reproducing the content of his link here to prevent the ironic future outcome of linkrot on an answer to a question about linkrot.

This is a simple CSV file with a header line produced from the Google Sheets export function.

```
Setting,Type/AP,Lvl Min,Max,Title,Issue#,Link
DS,Side Trek,3,20,Traveling the Athasian Wastes,202,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/202/202_Traveling_the_Athasian_Wastes.pdf
DS,,1,1,The Vault of Darom Madar,181,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/181/181_Vault.pdf
DS,,5,7,Revenge of the Maurauders,183,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/183/183_Revenge.pdf
DS,,6,8,Cruel as a Desert Wind,202,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/202/dnd_dun_DesertWind.pdf
DS,,7,9,Beneath the Dust,187,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/187/187_Beneath_the_Dust.pdf
DS,,8,10,The Isle of Death,202,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/202/dnd_dun_IsleOfDeath.pdf
Eberron,,6,8,Dark Lantern,214,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/214/Dungeon214.pdf
Eberron,,7,9,Dead for a Spell,206,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/206/206_DeadSpell.pdf
Eberron,,7,7,Heart of the Forbidden Forge,167,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/167_forbiddenforge.pdf
Eberron,,15,15,The Maze of Shattered Souls,177,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/177/177_Maze_of_Shattered_Souls.pdf
FR,AD&D,1,1,The Sun Never Rises,216,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/216/Dungeon216.pdf
FR,Legacy of the Crystal Shard,4,6,King of the Wolves,220,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/220/Dungeon220.pdf
FR,Neverwinter,1,3,Shard of Selûne,193,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/193/193_ShardofSelune.pdf
FR,Neverwinter,3,5,That Which Never Sleeps,195,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/195/195_ThatWhichNeverSleeps.pdf
FR,Neverwinter,3,5,The Gauntlgrym Gambit,193,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/193/193_GauntlgrymGambit.pdf
FR,Side Trek,11,15,Ruins of Starmantle,161,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/161_starmantle.pdf
FR,,1,1,Menace of the Icy Spire,159,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/159_icy_spire.pdf
FR,,1,2,Rats in the Undercellar,217,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/217/Dungeon217.pdf
FR,,1,1,The Dawn of Night,218,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/218/Dungeon218.pdf
FR,,1,3,The Elder Elemental Eye,241,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/214/Dungeon214.pdf
FR,,6,8,Eyes on the Ball,206,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/206/206_EyesBall.pdf
FR,,6,8,The Vulture’s Feast,210,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/210/Dungeon210.pdf
FR,,6,8,What’s Up in Downshadow,204,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/204/dnd_dun_Downshadow.pdf
FR,,7,9,Vainglorious,221,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/221/Dungeon221.pdf
FR,,13,13,Monuments of the Ancients,170,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/170/170_Monument.pdf
FR,,16,16,The Spiral Gate,180,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/180/180_Spiral_Gate.pdf
GH,AD&D,3,5,Lowdown in Highport,221,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/221/Dungeon221.pdf
GH,AD&D,6,9,The Last Slave Lord,215,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/215/Dungeon215.pdf
GH,D&D Next,5,7,The Battle of Emridy Meadows,221,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/221/Dungeon221.pdf
GH,D&D Next,14,16,Tomb of Horrors,213,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/213/Dungeon213.pdf
GH,White Plume Mountain,4,6,Never Say Die,212,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/212/Dungeon212.pdf
GH,,3,5,The Village of Hommlet,212,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/212/Dungeon212.pdf
GH,,20,22,Flame’s Last Flicker,200,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/200/dnd_dun_flamesflicker.pdf
KT,,5,7,The Five Deadly Shadows,195,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/195/195_Five_Deadly_Shadows.pdf
PoL,Against the Giants,12,14,Steading of the Hill Giant Chief,197,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/197/197_dnd_dun_steadinghillgiant.pdf
PoL,Against the Giants,14,16,Warrens of the Stone Giant Thane,198,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/198/198_AtG_WarrensOfStoneGiant.pdf
PoL,Against the Giants,16,18,Glacial Rift of the Frost Giant Jarl,199,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/199/dnd_dun_giants3.pdf
PoL,Against the Giants,18,20,Hall of the Fire Giant King,200,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/200/dnd_dun_giants4.pdf
PoL,Castle Ravenloft,5,7,Fair Barovia,207,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/207/Dungeon207Oct2012.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,1,1,A Chance Encounter,174,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/174/174_CS_Chance_Encounter.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,1,1,Death in the Pincers,172,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/172/172_CS_Pincers.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,1,1,Den of the Slave-Takers,171,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/171/171_CS_Den_ot_Slavers.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,1,1,Elves of the Valley,178,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/178/178_CS_Elves_of_the_Valley.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,1,1,Eyes in the Forest,177,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/177/177_CS_Eyes_in_the_Forest.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,1,1,Stick in the Mud,171,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/171/171_CS_StickInTheMud.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,1,1,Tainted Spiral,173,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/173/173_CS_Tainted_Spiral.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,1,1,The Brothers Gray,172,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/172/172_CS_Brothers_Gray.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,2,2,Dead by Dawn,176,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/176/176_CS_Dead_By_Dawn.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,2,2,Down the Goblin Hole,180,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/180/180_CS_Down_the_Goblin_Hole.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,2,2,Sliver's Call,174,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/174/174_CS_Slivers_Call.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,2,2,The Crossroads,176,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/176/176_CS_The_Crossroads.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,2,2,The Hammer Falls,179,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/179/179_CS_The_Hammer_Falls.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,2,2,The Lost Library,173,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/173/173_CS_Lost_Library.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,2,2,The Shrine of Glass-spire Forest,175,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/175/175_CS_Glass_Spire_Forest.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,3,3,The Splintered Spring,179,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/179/179_CS_Splintered_Spring.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,3,3,The Wayward Wyrmling,182,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/182/182_CS_Wayward_Wyrmling.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,4,4,Glowstone Caverns,177,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/177/177_CS_Glowstone_Caverns.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,4,4,The Crawling Fane,178,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/178/178_CS_The_Crawling_Fane.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,4,4,The Pillar of Eyes,180,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/180/180_CS_Pillar_of_Eyes.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,4,4,Vanguard Tower,182,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/182/182_CS_Vanguard.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,5,7,Scarred For Life,192,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/192/192_Scarred_for_Life.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,5,5,The Slaver's Stone,181,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/181/181_CS_Slavers_Stone.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,6,8,Rumble in the Valley,193,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/193/193_RumbleValley.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,6,8,The Radiant Morn,183,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/183/183_CS_Radiant_Morn.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,7,9,Head in the Clouds,184,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/184/184_Head_in_the_Clouds.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,7,7,Reflections of Ruin,196,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/196/196_Reflections_of_Ruin.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,7,9,Scarblade,189,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/189/189_CS_Scarblade.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,8,10,Pit of Delirium,190,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/190/190_PitOfDelirium.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,9,11,Heart of the Scar,197,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/197/197_heartofscar.pdf
PoL,Chaos Scar,10,12,The Runecutter's Ruin,186,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/186/186_CS_Runecutter.pdf
PoL,Dungeon Delve,1,1,Coppernight's Salvation,178,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/178/178_Coppernights_Salvation.pdf
PoL,Dungeon Delve,8,8,Return of the Poisoned Shadows,164,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/164_dungeondelve.pdf
PoL,Dungeon Delve,11,11,Crown of the Troll King,169,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/169_delve_trollking.pdf
PoL,Dungeon Delve,12,14,The Whispering Glade,185,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/185/185_Whispering_Glade.pdf
PoL,Dungeon Delve,18,18,Summer's End,160,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/160_summers_end.pdf
PoL,Map Trek,21,23,The Sword Collector,204,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/204/dnd_dun_SwordCollector.pdf
PoL,Red box,2,2,The Dungeon of the Ghost Tower,182,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/182/182_Ghost_Tower.pdf
PoL,Scales of War,1,2,Rescue at Rivenroar,156,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/dungeon/156/156_sow_rivenroar.pdf
PoL,Scales of War,3,3,Siege of Bordrin's Watch,157,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/dungeon/157/157_bordrinswatch.pdf
PoL,Scales of War,4,5,The Shadow Rift of the Umbraforge,158,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/dungeon/158/158_umbraforge.pdf
PoL,Scales of War,6,6,The Lost Mine of Karak,159,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/159_sow_lost_mines.pdf
PoL,Scales of War,7,9,Den of the Destroyer,160,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/160_sow_destroyer.pdf
PoL,Scales of War,9,10,The Temple Between,161,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/161_sow_templebetween.pdf
PoL,Scales of War,10,11,Fist of Mourning,162,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/162_sow_fistofmourning.pdf
PoL,Scales of War,11,12,Beyond the Mottled Tower,163,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/163_sow_mottledtower.pdf
PoL,Scales of War,12,14,Haven of the Bitter Glass,164,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/164_bitterglass.pdf
PoL,Scales of War,14,15,Alliance at Nefelus,165,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/165_allianceatnefelus.pdf
PoL,Scales of War,15,17,Throne of the Stone-Skinned King,166,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/166_stone-skin_king.pdf
PoL,Scales of War,17,19,Garaitha's Anvil,167,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/167_garaithas_anvil.pdf
PoL,Scales of War,19,21,A Tyranny of Souls,168,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/168_tyranny.pdf
PoL,Scales of War,21,22,Betrayal at Monadhan,170,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/170_monadhan.pdf
PoL,Scales of War,22,24,Grasp of the Mantled Citadel,171,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/171/171_SoW_Mantled_Citadel.pdf
PoL,Scales of War,24,25,Legacy of Io,172,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/172/172_SoW_Legacy_of_Io.pdf
PoL,Scales of War,25,27,Those Once Loyal,173,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/173/173_SoW_Once_Loyal.pdf
PoL,Scales of War,27,29,Test of Fire,174,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/174/174_SoW_Test_of_Fire.pdf
PoL,Scales of War,30,30,Last Breath of Tiamat,175,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/175/175_SoW_Last_Breath.pdf
PoL,Side Trek,1,3,Shadow of Kalarel,155,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/dungeon/155/155_Shadowfell_SideTrek.pdf
PoL,Side trek,2,2,The Slaying Stone : The Den of Dreus,179,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/179/179_Den_of_Dreus.pdf
PoL,Side Trek,4,5,Death and Taxes,201,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/201/201_Death_and_Taxes.pdf
PoL,Side Trek,4,6,Echoes of Thunderspire Labyrinth,156,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/dungeon/156/156_ThunderspireSideTrek.pdf
PoL,Side Trek,4,4,Nightmares Unleashed,177,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/177/177_Nightmares_Unleashed.pdf
PoL,Side Trek,5,5,Hidden Destinies,175,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/175/175_Hidden_Destinies.pdf
PoL,Side Trek,7,7,Treed!,171,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/171/171_Treed.pdf
PoL,Side Trek,9,9,House of Pain,163,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/163_houseofpain.pdf
PoL,Side Trek,11,11,Beyond the Trollhaunt,160,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/160_st_trollhaunt.pdf
PoL,Side Trek,11,11,Hall of the Snake God,169,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/169_snake_god.pdf
PoL,The Tear of Ioun,10,11,Touch of Madness,161,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/161_touchofmadness.pdf
PoL,The Tear of Ioun,11,12,Depths of Madness,162,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/162_depthsofmadness.pdf
PoL,The Tear of Ioun,13,13,Brink of Madness,163,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/163_brinkofmadness.pdf
PoL,,0,0,Temple of the Weeping Goddess,194,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/194/194_TempleoftheWeepingGoddess.pdf
PoL,,1,3,Beyond the Crystal Cave,211,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/211/Dungeon211.pdf
PoL,,1,20,Cross City Race,176,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/176/176_Cross-City_Race.pdf
PoL,,1,3,Dark Legacy of Evard,219,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/219/Dungeon219.pdf
PoL,,1,1,Glitterdust,211,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/211/Dungeon211.pdf
PoL,,1,1,Prey for Smiley Bob,205,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/205/dnd_dun_SmileyBob.pdf
PoL,,1,3,Some Assembly Required,208,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/208/Dungeon_208_Nov12.pdf
PoL,,2,4,Captain Slygo’s Treasure,208,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/208/Dungeon_208_Nov12.pdf
PoL,,2,4,Fall of the Gray Veil,211,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/211/Dungeon211.pdf
PoL,,2,4,Slaark’s Crown,220,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/220/Dungeon220.pdf
PoL,,3,5,A Rhyme Gone Wrong,217,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/217/Dungeon217.pdf
PoL,,3,8,Andok Sur,187,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/187/187_Andok_Sur.pdf
PoL,,3,5,Battle of the Witchlight Hermitage,191,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/191/191_BattleWitchlightHermitage.pdf
PoL,,3,5,Evard's Shadow ,192,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/192/192_Evards_Shadow.pdf
PoL,,3,5,Fjorin’s Foothold,209,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/209/Dungeon209.pdf
PoL,,3,3,Storm Tower,166,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/166_stormtower.pdf
PoL,,3,5,The Sunker Tower of the Marsh Mystic,186,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/186/186_Marsh_Mystic.pdf
PoL,,3,3,The Tariff of Relkingham,158,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/dungeon/158/158_tariff_of_relkingham.pdf
PoL,,4,6,Blood of Gruumsh,210,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/210/Dungeon210.pdf
PoL,,4,6,Dead Heaven,218,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/218/Dungeon218.pdf
PoL,,4,4,Heathen,155,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/dungeon/155/155_Heathen.pdf
PoL,,4,6,Infernal Wrath,205,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/205/dnd_dun_InfernalWrath.pdf
PoL,,4,6,Leader of the Pack,194,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/194/194_LeaderofthePack.pdf
PoL,,4,6,Owlbear Run,213,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/213/Dungeon213.pdf
PoL,,4,4,Remains of the Empire,165,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/165_remainsoftheempire.pdf
PoL,,4,4,Stormcrow Tor,169,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/169_stormcrowtor.pdf
PoL,,4,6,The Dread Pirate Braxis,213,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/213/Dungeon213.pdf
PoL,,5,7,A Knight in Shadowghast Manor,197,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/197/197_dnd_dun_kinghtshadowghast.pdf
PoL,,5,7,Bark at the moon,185,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/duad/20101209
PoL,,5,7,Going Ape,192,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/192/192_Going_Ape.pdf
PoL,,6,8,Lord of the White Field,184,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/184/184_White_Field.pdf
PoL,,6,6,Siege of Gardmore Abbey,210,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/210/Dungeon210.pdf
PoL,,6,6,Tyrant's Oath,178,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/178/178_Tyrants_Oath.pdf
PoL,,7,9,Blood Money,200,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/200/dnd_dun_bloodmoney.pdf
PoL,,7,9,Massacre at Misty River,216,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/216/Dungeon216.pdf
PoL,,7,9,No Rest for the Wicked,214,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/214/Dungeon214.pdf
PoL,,7,7,Oasis of the Golden Peacock,169,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/169_oasisgoldenpeacock.pdf
PoL,,7,7,Secrets of the White Lotus Academy,165,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/374_whitelotusacademy.pdf
PoL,,7,7,The Hidden Shrine of Tamoachan,209,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/209/Dungeon209.pdf
PoL,,8,8,Massacre at Fort Dolor,157,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/dungeon/157/157_Fort_Dolor.pdf
PoL,,8,10,Reign of Despair,191,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/191/191_ReignofDespair.pdf
PoL,,8,8,Sleeper in the Tomb of Dreams,155,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/dungeon/155/155_Sleeper.pdf
PoL,,8,8,The Last Breaths of Ashenport,156,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/dungeon/156/156_Ashenport.pdf
PoL,,8,9,The Star-Touched Grove,219,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/219/Dungeon219.pdf
PoL,,9,11,Force of Nature,190,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/190/190_ForceOfNature.pdf
PoL,,9,10,Legacy of Ghere Thau,218,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/218/Dungeon218.pdf
PoL,,10,12,Baelard's Legacy,188,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/188/188_Legacy.pdf
PoL,,10,12,Children of Ardore,220,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/220/Dungeon220.pdf
Pol,,10,10,The Dark Heart of Mithrendain,157,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/dungeon/157/157_dark_heart.pdf
PoL,,11,13,Killing Ground,189,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/189/189_Killing_Ground.pdf
PoL,,11,13,The Art of Deception,217,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/217/Dungeon217.pdf
PoL,,12,12,The Haunting of Kincep Mansion,156,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/dungeon/156/156_Kincep_Mansion.pdf
PoL,,12,12,Worse then Death,164,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/164_worsethandeath.pdf
PoL,,13,15,Baba Yaga’s Dancing Hut,196,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/196/196_Baba_Yagas_Hut.pdf
PoL,,13,13,Clash of Steel,172,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/172/172_Clash_of_Steel.pdf
PoL,,13,15,Grasp of Thalarkis,203,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/203/203_Grasp%20of%20Thalarkis.pdf
PoL,,13,13,In the Depths of Avarice,157,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/dungeon/157/157_Depths_of_Avarice.pdf
PoL,,13,13,Web of Chains,168,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/168_webofchains.pdf
PoL,,14,16,Hunt for the Heretic,203,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/203/dnd_dun_Hunt4Heretic.pdf
PoL,,15,17,Pearl of the Sea Mother,204,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/204/dnd_dun_Pearl_of_SeaMother.pdf
PoL,,15,15,Sea Reavers of the Shrouded Crags,158,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/dungeon/158/158_Sea_Reavers.pdf
PoL,,15,17,Starhaunt,207,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/207/Dungeon207Oct2012.pdf
PoL,,15,17,Tears of the Crocodile God,209,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/209/Dungeon209.pdf
PoL,,16,16,Faarlung's Algorithm,179,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/179/179_Faarlungs_Algorithm.pdf
PoL,,16,18,Face of the Moon,201,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/201/dnd_dun_facemoon.pdf
PoL,,17,19,Devil's Due,188,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/188/188_Devils_Due.pdf
PoL,,17,20,Some Like It Hot,216,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/216/Dungeon216.pdf
PoL,,21,23,The Rolling Tomb,215,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/215/Dungeon215.pdf
PoL,,21,21,The Ziggurat beyond Time,159,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/159_ziggurat.pdf
PoL,,21,23,Unfriendly Skies,205,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/205/dnd_dun_UnfriendlySkies.pdf
PoL,,22,22,Winter of the Witch,162,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/162_winterofthewitch.pdf
PoL,,25,27,Blades of the Stygian Masque,219,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/219/Dungeon219.pdf
PoL,,25,25,Tomb of the Sand King's Daughter,160,http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Downloads/160_sand_king.pdf
PoL,,28,30,Court of the Dark Prince,212,http://www.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/212/Dungeon212.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick search turned up this:

[D&D4 Wiki - List of published adventure](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_published_adventures)

I'm not sure how up to date it is.

Comment: Given that this question was spawned by a dead link, giving a link only answer is a sweet kind of cruel irony.